# what is the advantage of using mixin pattern with classes?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Example extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){

       navigateToObjectHome(){
          this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                 type: 'standard__objectPage',
                 attributes:{
                       objectApiName : 'Account',
                        actionName: 'home'
                    },
             });
        }

}
```

as to my understanding of this pattern "this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]"
points to a method in our custom Example class that comes possibly from LightningElement so the NavigationMixin
acts as a middle man only providing the name of  property: "NavigationMixin.Navigate" to point to the method in
our custom Example class. Agian what is the advantage of it?

Comment: 1/2 ... I expect `NavigationMixin.Navigate` to be a constant string value, where the value is a method name (key) which is managed by the provider of the *"lightning"*  library / module. The advantage of such an hopefully documented design choice comes with the freedom of changing values with later version without breaking the code of the library's users/consumers. Thus `NavigationMixin` here acts just as a namespace. A use case like this (despite the examples namespace name) also has not the slightest in common with any mixin pattern.

Comment: 2/2 ... But on the actually used pattern which claims to be a mixin which does extend the `Example` class I want to add my two cents on the `NavigationMixin(LightningElement)` part - **Note:** Functions of the pattern function `MyMixin(superClass) { return class extends superClass { /* implementation */ }; }` where the return value is an ad-hoc created anonymous class (which then mostly is used for sub-typing of another class) are factory functions. There is nothing involved in terms of mixin and/or composition. Everything from its implementation to its usage is dedicated to pure inheritance.